# Why dpkg-reconfigure is trying to reconfigure packages which are not installed?

Tags: package-management

I tried to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a` but I got glib-networking-services is not installed and no info. I checked the package and it is not installed, but should it reconfigure the installed packages only? Why is it trying to reconfigure a package which is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps configured, but not installed?

Can I see the output of:

```
$ dpkg -l glib-networking-services
```

Please?